# Heroku use Options instead of POST method

Tags: express

I deployed my backend API on Heroku and now trying to call it with frontend API. When I do that and check logs it show that the method used is OPTIONS instead of POST and doesn't return anything. However when I make request from Postman it shows method as POST. The same backend code and frontend when deployed in localhost works perfectly fine.

Heroku Logs above one shows request from frontend and below is request from Post Man:

```
2020-09-22T04:50:00.422091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/api/signin" host=****-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=b93d3a15-23cf-42df-93f1-125d79017edf fwd="****" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=215 protocol=https
2020-09-22T04:50:00.422973+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mOPTIONS /api/signin [32m200[0m 4.063 ms - 4[0m

2020-09-22T04:54:53.827158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/signin" host=****-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=91ccaa0c-e676-48aa-8856-364a1413460b fwd="****" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=60ms status=200 bytes=770 protocol=https
2020-09-22T04:54:53.822533+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mPOST /api/signin [32m200[0m 52.224 ms - 361[0m
```

My frontend action code:

```
export const signin = (user) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/signin`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },

    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: Possibly the `OPTIONS` is a CORS preflight request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), used by browsers to determine whether the server allows cross site requests.

Comment: But then why there is no POST request after the OPTIONS method

Comment: Likely your server isn't responding with the appropriate headers; `Access-Control-Allow-*`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers etc). The easiest thing will be to find an appropriate CORS package for your server framework/language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPTIONS is default method that call by browser to check connection with server.
Postman is not browser based call so it can make direct POST request.

You need to handle OPTIONS method on Heroku and return 200 status code. that should solve your problem.

if you're using express.js then you can add below in your code to handle OPTIONS method.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // handle OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Dipten, Solution provided by you worked Like a CHARM!! Thank you so much for help. Couldn't solve this problem from very long time

Comment: Be careful using the wild card `*` when setting `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` as it will allow incoming requests from everywhere and it's not secure unless you really intend to do it https://www.positronx.io/express-cors-tutorial/

Comment: Glad to hear that it solved your problem. Please accept this answer.

Comment: When I add this to mine with the same issue, does not change anything.  I am getting the same method=options, when I send a POST. Also it works fine from local machine but when try it from hosted website it shows as method=options, any ideas?

Comment: @MorganHayes Please mention Node.js framework with version and sample code so i can give solution for you.

Comment: "express": "^4.17.1",

Comment: "express": "^4.17.1", for the API. What code would you like, the website or the API? Is there a better way to reach you?

Comment: i started another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989324/heroku-send-post-receives-as-options