# heroku send post receives as options

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, heroku

I have deployed an API on Heroku and when i send post request from my website the Heroku logs show method=options and the does not work.
When I send from my local machine, Heroku logs show method=post and all works great.

I have found this post in StackOverflow [Heroku use Options instead of POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003377/heroku-use-options-instead-of-post-method) but that solution does not solve my issue.

Heroku logs, first is from local, second is from website:

```
2022-10-06T23:57:19.315699+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/smsNotif/applySmsNotif" host=***** request_id=88da98c7-f136-4775-a52a-b10b104b2cff fwd="****" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=462 protocol=https

2022-10-07T00:01:05.970299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/api/smsNotif/applySmsNotif" host=***** request_id=039a51c3-a976-47f7-bd03-4c52bc71361f fwd="****" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=277 protocol=https
```

my request is from axios on a hosted website:

```
api({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/smsNotif/applySmsNotif",
        data: appData,
      });
```

API code to fix the method=options:

```
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: ['https://forms.ccenttcs.com/', 'http://localhost:9002'], }))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // handle OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: the OPTIONS request is known as a [CORS "preflight request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) that is sent first to verify with the server that the actual POST request is safe to send.  If the POST request isn't being sent, the OPTIONS request is being returned with a negative "not safe" result.  You need to determine why that is based on what/how you're sending and receiving.

Comment: thank you, I add more code to the question. code that was planned to fix the options method.

Comment: You should't need to manually handle the OPTIONS method when also using CORS middleware.  They are both doing the same thing so in my opinion you should just use the middleware.  You can set the allowed headers by adding to your [CORS configuration](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options).  If you're still having trouble can you post the OPTIONS request sent by your browser so we can see exactly what it's requesting, along with what error is being returned?

Comment: I found that i needed to reload a few times to get it to work. When i remove the "handle the options method" it does not work. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few reloads the original code worked, from([Heroku use Options instead of POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003377/heroku-use-options-instead-of-post-method))

Thank you @Dipten

One thing to watch for is in :

```
app.use(cors({ origin: ['https://forms.ccenttcs.com/', 'http://localhost:9002'], }))
```

I use my API for multiple apps and I need to have all of them listed for CORS  in the code above.

```
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: ['https://forms.ccenttcs.com/', 'http://localhost:9002'], }))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // handle OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle option method work only without cors module.
As you use cors module so you need to make following changes.

```
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: ['https://forms.ccenttcs.com/', 'http://localhost:9002'], }))
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes
```

if you face CORS error then change cors config by removing origin and test.

```
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Thanks @dipten , your original code worked great, I think I needed a couple of reloads to it going.